# MS Teams Bot fetching data from Amazon Connect

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, amazon-connect

I am looking for a way to have a bot setup that will fetch data from Amazon Connect (which is a web page that shows call statuses like incoming, in queue etc).

The bot should ideally be able to pick a field from the page and say "welp we got 5 calls waiting to be answered" and announce that in the team channel.

I dont have admin rights on the channel or my computer (work computer -.-) so that limits some solutions which require admin access, but open to suggestions regardless.

Thanks
mapy

Comment: You can configure [incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) in a Teams channel & can post or send card from custom WebPage as and when required. or you can [embedd the webpage as tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/embedded-web-experiences/) and get those details from there.